# Inner automorphisms and $K$-theory

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

It is known that any inner automorphism of a unital $C^{\ast}$-algebra $A$ induces the identity map on $K_{0}(A)$ because unitary equivalence implies Murray-von Neumann equivalence. What is known about the induced map on $K_{1}(A)$?

Comment: For example, if the inner automorphism is homotopic to identity, then the induced map on $K_{1}(A)$ is the identity map. But, this is too strong. Does there exist any weaker condition? What is known when $A=C(\mathbb{T},M_{n}(\mathbb{C}))$?

Comment: Crossposted to math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406088/induced-map-on-k-1-group

Answer (score 5):

Inner automorphisms also induce the identity map on $K_1(A)$.

Let $u\in A$ be the unitary inducing the inner automorphism $\alpha$.  Let $x$ be a unitary $n\times n$-matrix over $A$.  Then $\alpha(x)$ is equal to $u_nxu_n^*$ where $u_n$ is the diagonal matrix with all diagonal entries $u$.  Hence the class in $K_1(A)$ of $\alpha(u)$ is $[u_nxu_n^*]=[u_n]+[x]-[u_n]=[x]$.